# Cordova App builds are failing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cordova

Cordova app builds are failing in Android Studio, irrespective of whether the build is on an Emulator or a physically connected device. This has been a recent issue that came up, prior to which builds were going through without any issues.

****Java Version:**
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_382-8u382-ga-1~22.04.1-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)

**Gradle Version:** 7.4.2

**Android Studio Version:**
Giraffe 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023

Trying to build an Cordova app on an Android Emulator/Physical Device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.